# How do I indicate a unit number in an Australian postal address?

Tags: writing, australian-english

How do you indicate a unit number when writing the postal address of snail mail?

Australia Post's [Addressing guidelines](http://auspost.com.au/parcels-mail/addressing-guidelines.html) does not mention how to indicate unit numbers.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_%28geography%29#Australia) states that for a flat or apartment, you should have the unit number, then a forward slash, then the street number. However, it does not have a citation for that.

Comment: I think this is Too Localised for an English Learners site. FWIW, I would put the flat/unit number on a separate line (as *"Flat 3"*, or *"Unit 6a"*, etc.) after the name, and before the "second to last line" containing the "[building] number and name of the street" as mentioned in your link.

Comment: Actually, I've got to go with Off Topic. This question does not relate to learning English at all, but rather to learning how to properly use the postal service.

Comment: @KenB: More specifically, the *Australian* postal service. But yeah, you're right - it's more Off Topic than Too Localised.

Comment: 6a/100 Main Street, U6a/100 Main Street, Unit 6a/100 Main Street.  All of those are acceptable and all are equally likely to end up getting lost in the post.

Comment: This post has received 10K views.

Comment: Yes, I can imagine that people would have questions about mail, learners or not. But it's still oft-topic for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I have found a very useful document from Australia Post: https://auspost.com.au/media/documents/australia-post-addressing-standards-1999.pdf. It might be a little old according to its filename, but it clearly describes how to format unit numbers. It should be like `U 2  17 Jones St` or `2/17 Jones St`. Please note that it is preferred that there are 2 spaces between the unit number and the street number when using the first format.

Comment: This still shows up quite highly in search engine results when searching this question, for a couple different wordings of it. Thought I'd pop the answer I found from Auspost after a bit of digging. Page 3 of this [document](https://auspost.com.au/content/dam/auspost_corp/media/documents/Appendix-01.pdf). If anyone knows a more appropriate part of StackExchange for this question, feel free to throw the link there as an answer for me :)